# Nginx redirect all contents of a subdirectory to another subdirectory

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Let say that I have a url like this:

http://www.example.com/admin/admin.php?fail=1

how can I rewrite the url to be

http://www.example.com/another/subdirectory/admin.php?fail=1

Thank you

---

**Update: this is what I've tried so far, but it will not redirect admin.php?fail=1**

```
location /admin/ {
    rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ 
    /another/subdirectory/$1 redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I rather use return 301 for redirections and use rewrite only if I want to display something like a nice url.

Please try the following

```
location  ~ ^/admin/(.*) {
    return 301  /another/subdirectory/$1 ;
}
```