# Nginx send all requests from subdirectory to php-fpm?

Tags: php, nginx

how can i redirect all requests going to `/api/v1/*ANYTHING*` to `/api/v1/router.php` ? my current nginx config is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /srv/http/default/www;
    autoindex on;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

and things i have tried:

```
location /api/v1 {
    try_files FIXME_DO_NOT_MAKE_FILE_WITH_THIS_NAME /api/v1/router.php$is_args$args;
}
```

- this almost works, for example `/api/v1/get/123` works.. but it does not work if the url ends with .php, for example `/api/v1/get/123.php` will not be redirected, resulting in a 404 Not Found if get/123.php does not exist.
  (and yeah, the dummy is apparently mandatory, with 1 argument i get an error that try_files requires a minimum of 2 arguments, and with `try_files /api/v1/router.php =500;`, it just prints the php source code rather than sending it to php-fpm)

have also tried:

```
location /api/v1 {
    rewrite ^/api/v1/(.*)$ /api/v1/router.php last;
}
```

.. which seems to suffer from exactly the same issue as above, as long as the url does not end in `.php` it works, otherwise i get 404's... i guess it has something to do with the `location ~ \.php$` block taking precedence, but it doesn't matter if i put my rewrite rule above or below the .php$ block... so now i'm kindof stumped

(also not sure if this question belongs on SO or serverfault or superuser, but given that similar questions like [Nginx redirect all requests from subdirectory to another subdirectory root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224441/nginx-redirect-all-requests-from-subdirectory-to-another-subdirectory-root) exists on SO, i decided on trying here)

Comment: try ´location /api/v1 {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/api/v1/router.php$is_args$args permanent;
}´

Comment: @BRBonn still gives 404 for `http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/dsalkfwkwg.php`

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution would be to define a "regex" location, and directly specify script name that will be the one processing all requests, like so:

```
location ~ ^/api/v1/ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/api/v1/router.php;
}
```

Make sure to put this *above* the `location ~ \.php$ {` because NGINX checks regex locations in order of appearance in configuration files.

Comment: for some reason that is giving me 404s for `http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/DJ` - it does not generate anything in nginx error logs, and the access log looks normal. for the record, here is the config file i'm using: https://pastebin.com/raw/MyeYMWcf and i tried putting the location~ above and below the .php$, didn't make a difference, i also tried specifying an absolute path instead of $document_root , here is the entire nginx config folder just in case it helps, but it's  a just standard ubuntu configuration https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/WVWPEOi6ItAJRTl5Tda80Q/raw?password=zooXnim1UjJgpCbXkl

Comment: i'm not 100% happy with this work around, but renaming the folder to internal_v1 and then using ```location ~ ^/api/v1/ {
 try_files FIXME_DO_NOT_MAKE_FILE_WITH_THIS_NAME /api/internal_v1/router.php$is_args$args;
}
``` seems to work.. not sure why, also as you said, making it a regex is important, just doing ```location /api/v1/``` does not work, it has to be ```location ~ ^/api/v1/``` - tl;dr: found a workaround, but not happy with it