# NGINX redirect from subdirectory to root with Slim API framework

Tags: php, nginx, kubernetes, slim, nginx-ingress

I want to forward requests to the subdirectory v1 (subdomain.domain.com/v1) to my root in Nginx. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443468/nginx-location-configuration-subfolders) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224441/nginx-redirect-all-requests-from-subdirectory-to-another-subdirectory-root) answer (and more variations) with no success. I use the Slim API framework.

My nginx config looks like this:

```
    events {
}
http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    location /healthcheck {
      auth_basic off;
      allow all;
      return 200;
    }
    location / {
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php$1 last;
      }
    }
    #location ~ \.php {
    # only allow index.php to be proxied to FastCGI process (more secure than all php files!)
    location /index.php {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    location location ~ ^/v1/(.*) {
      return 301 $scheme://$http_host/$1$is_args$query_string;
    }
  }
}
```

My ingress yaml (Kubernetes) looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: ingress-ENVIRONMENT_NAME_SHORT-NAME_OF_DEPLOYMENT
 namespace: NAME_OF_NAMESPACE
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
   kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ip-ENVIRONMENT_NAME_SHORT-NAME_OF_DEPLOYMENT
   networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: cert-ENVIRONMENT_NAME_SHORT-NAME_OF_DEPLOYMENT
   kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: NAME_OF_DOMAIN
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /v1/*
            backend:
              serviceName: svc-ENVIRONMENT_NAME_SHORT-NAME_OF_DEPLOYMENT
              servicePort: 443
```

I only get this thing to run without /v1 (just subdomain.domain.com). Any guidance appreciated.

UPDATE (Jun 2021): in SLIM 4 this is now as easy as it gets:
$app->setBasePath("/index.php/v1");

Answer (score 2):

The best approach I believe is to have the redirect happen at the ingress level or even prior to hitting the ingress. However, GCE ingress doesn't support [HTTP to HTTPS](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/1075) redirects yet, let alone any kind of redirect.

The way you have it, is basically this way: the ingress gets a `/v1` request then it goes to Nginx and then it says redirect to `/` but that redirect request goes back to the ingress which says I don't know what to do with `/` request.

Another approach is just to have your backend serve on `/v1` or use a two-layered approach which is pretty common.  GCE LB (with no ingress controller) ➡️  Nginx ingress (which does the redirect and has a much richer feature set) ➡️ backend.

Comment: For many reasons I want to stick with the gce ingress controller. This ("Another approach is just to have your backend serve on /v1..") is interesting. I guess exactly what I am looking for. I only have the code for v1 on the php-fpm and nginx server, nothing else. For a potential v2 I would add that path in ingress and have a different backend (with another nginx running)

Comment: How can I achieve this? I am flexible to bring my files into a subfolder v1 (which I tried) but failed with nginx config

Comment: I didn't mean bring the files to `v1` folder. I meant basically have your service actually server under `v1`. Something like if you were to access it through localhost it would be like `http://127.0.0.1/v1/`

Comment: Probably I do not understand this. I managed to get it running with a normal php file, just phpinof() (but not with SLIM): location / { try_files $uri /index.php; } and location ~ \.php {  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000; }. I can forward any request to index.php, since this is the only file needed under v1. Guess I am missing to give the path to Slim (I see it forwards any request with 301 to v1 then again to v1 returning 404).

Comment: Sorry last part in bracket is wrong: directly 404, the 301 was in cache

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with php when you want to serve under `/v1` by typically other frameworks you can set a path where you want to serve from.  I may not be possible with php, in which case you'll have to find other alternatives.